# How to populate a text field from a string array ios and change it via page curl animation

Tags: ios, arrays

I'm attempting to populate a string array separated by /n from a text file. Then with the string array i want to populate a text field that i can iterate to the next item in the array via a page curl animation.

textfile>stringarray>textfield>change text field via page curl.

So far i have figured out how to do something similar via a button but i want to change the trigger for the next iteration to the user flicking to the next page.

Whats the best way to approach this? I have looked at a few tutorials on the page curl animation and ive tried to find ibook like apps but nothing seems to have the right components im looking for.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var x = 0


@IBOutlet var quoteOfTheDay: UILabel!
@IBAction func printarray(_ sender: Any) {
    if x<arrayFromFile().count {

    print(arrayFromFile()[x])

        quoteOfTheDay.text = arrayFromFile()[x]
        x+=1
    }
    else{
        print("that's all folks")
        quoteOfTheDay.text = "Happy New Year"
    }
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func arrayFromFile() ->[String] {
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "CalendarQuotes", ofType: "txt"){
        do{
            let data = try String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: .utf8)
            return data.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        } catch {
            return [String]()

        }


        }

        return [String]()

    }
```

}

The animation code i managed to get working for animation but can't figure out how to get it to trigger x+=1 to cycle through my array. Right now its button based but id like it to be gesture based

```
- (IBAction)didTapHalfCurlUpBtn:(id)sender
{

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations:^{
                     CATransition *animation = [CATransition 
animation];
                     [animation setDuration:1.2];
                     [animation setTimingFunction:
[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:@"default"]];
                     animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
                     [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
                     animation.endProgress = 1;
                     animation.type = @"pageCurl";
                     [self.animatedUIView.layer addAnimation:animation 
forKey:@"pageFlipAnimation"];
                     [tempUIView removeFromSuperview];

                 }

 ];
}

- (IBAction)didTapCurlDownBtn:(id)sender
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations:^{
                     CATransition *animation = [CATransition 
animation];
                     [animation setDuration:1.2];
                     [animation setTimingFunction
[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:@"default"]];
                     animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
                     [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
                     animation.startProgress = 0.35;
                     animation.type = @"pageUnCurl";
                     [self.animatedUIView.layer addAnimation:animation 
forKey:@"pageUnCurlAnimation"];
                     [tempUIView removeFromSuperview];

                 }
 ];
```

Comment: I did the two halfs of my project seperately and realized one uses objective c and on uses swift. Gonna try to convert to all swift and hopeully that will allow me to add the swipe gesture as the trigger

Answer (score 0):

Use the `String` function `components(separatedBy:)` with a parameter of "\n" to break your string into an array of strings.

Then I would suggest using a page view controller (`UIPageViewController`) to set up a series of pages that are managed using a page curl transition. That's a native feature of a page view controller. There's a fair amount of overhead to create and manage a page view controller, but it will likely be less than setting up your own scheme for managing an array of views and handling pan gestures to transition between them.

You should be able to find a Swift tutorial on `UIPageViewController` online. The last time I used one was in Objective-C, but it's not really that hard.

Comment: Don't post code in a comment. It becomes and unreadable mess.

Comment: thanks @duncan i edited my question. I have now managed to get everything working perfectly except the page curl triggering the change of text on the label. Any suggestions on how to do that part?

Comment: Your code doesn't show anything related to page view controllers or page curl animations, or code to change the text for that matter. How can I offer advice about what to do next when I have no idea what you're doing now?

Comment: i added what i want to use for the animation however its in objective c and not swift and im struggling to combine them